# How can I have a "main" bootloader, on the first partition? (UEFI)

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, uefi, bootloader

I tried dual booting Windows and Xubuntu using a different approach. (It worked, but it wasn't the best)

Instead of doing what I belive most people do, which is replacing the Windows bootloader with GRUB, and putting Linux on a second partition, I installed Xubuntu and all of its files (including GRUB) on a separate partion without ever touching Windows.

[Picture to clarify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGcsU.png)

- Free space at the beginning: I'll explain shortly
- First 4 partitions: Untouched windows files
- 5th partition: All Xubuntu files, including the bootloader.
- 6th partition: Data partition (ignore)

Now I have 2 bootloaders, Windows Bootloader and GRUB, When i power on my laptop, it opens the first bootloader it finds (in this case, windows). If I want to boot Xubuntu, I open the boot menu and I see the only SSD I have, selecting the SSD will put me back in windows, so I select "Boot from EFI file", then i dig through some folders until i find grubx64.efi. I have to do this every time I want to run Xubuntu.

Is there a way I can put a "main bootloader" in the empty space at the beginning of my disk which i can use to open Windows Bootloader and GRUB. If so, which bootloader would you recommend, can it be a second GRUB, and how do I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of doing what I belive most people do, which is replacing the Windows bootloader with GRUB

That's not exactly what people do – kind of, yes, but they don't outright replace the Windows bootloader (nor the Windows boot manager) but rather configure GRUB to "chain-load" it. That is, their *first* GRUB installation already does what your supposed second GRUB would do.

But that kind of setup (and the whole idea of having to replace 'the' bootloader) is more relevant to older 'BIOS' systems. Your system firmware follows the UEFI specification and is not limited to one bootloader per disk in the first place, so while chain-loading Windows Bootmgr from GRUB is possible, it's not the only way.

> Is there a way I can put a "main bootloader" in the empty space at the beginning of my disk which i can use to open Windows Bootloader and GRUB.

Yes, but if it's just a "second GRUB" it wouldn't really be different from using the first GRUB to do the same thing.

However, this should already be part of your firmware – it's the same boot menu that lists the whole disk. In addition to listing each disk (which chooses the file "\EFI\Boot\Bootx64.efi" on the first compatible partition), the boot menu on any UEFI-compatible system already has the ability to show individual OS entries pointing to specific paths. An entry for Xubuntu's grubx64.efi should have been automatically added there as soon as you installed it, alongside the 'Windows Boot Manager' entry.

So if you're already using that menu, you should get it working properly – poke around with `efibootmgr` on Linux.

- From within Windows, [bcdboot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di?view=windows-11) can be used to reinstall Bootmgr as well as create the "Windows Boot Manager" UEFI boot entry if it's missing.

  ```
  bcdboot c:\windows /f uefi
  ```
- From Linux, `grub-install` will re-add the "GRUB" boot entry.

  ```
  grub-install --target=x86_64-efi
  ```
- You can add boot entries [manually](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr) using `efibootmgr`:

  ```
  efibootmgr --create --label="Xubuntu" --disk=/dev/nvme0n1 --part=1 --loader='\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi'
  ```

  The `--bootorder` option can then be used to set the default entry for all future boots. (Similarly, `--bootnext` can be used to select a different OS for *one* reboot.)

Comment: Most of the times, I only see windows as an option in the boot menu, so I manually select the efi file. can you clarify how can I have both bootloaders in the boot menu?

Comment: Re-run `grub-install` or manually do `efibootmgr --create` to add grubx64.efi to the list.